# PHP: CAPTCHA validation

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a Contact Us form.

My CAPTCHA validates with any random input and I do not know why... My comparator does not work. The other static validations work, such as first name, last name and email. The php validation happens server side

Please help...
Thanks in advance,  Mike C A

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$string = $_SESSION["random_code"];
$firstname = $lastname = $telephone = $email = $subject = $code = $message = "";
$errfirstname = $errlastname = $errtelephone = $erremail = $errsubject = $errcode = $errmessage = "";
function test_input($data) {
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  $data = strip_tags($data);
  return $data;
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
  if (empty(test_input($_POST["firstname"]))) {
    $errfirstname = "First name is required";
  } else {
    $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
      $errfirstname = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }
  $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
  if (empty(test_input($_POST["lastname"]))) {
    $errlastname = "Last name is required";
  } else {
    $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
      $errlastname = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }
  $telephone = test_input($_POST["telephone"]);
  if (empty(test_input($_POST["telephone"]))) {
    $errtelephone = "";
  } else {
    $telephone = test_input($_POST["telephone"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^\+[0-9]{7,18}$|^[0-9]{7,19}$/",$telephone)) {
      $errtelephone = "Only numbers and + signs allowed";
    }
  }
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  if (empty(test_input($_POST["email"]))) {
    $erremail = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $erremail = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }
  $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
  if (empty(test_input($_POST["subject"]))) {
    $errsubject = "";
  } else {
    $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    if (!preg_match("/[a-z|A-Z|0-9|\s]*/",$subject)) {
      $errsubject = "Up to 20 letters, numbers, and whitespace allowed";
    }
    if (strlen($subject) > 20) {
      $errsubject = "Up to 20 letters, numbers, and whitespace allowed";
    }
  }
  $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  if (empty(test_input($_POST["message"]))) {
    $errmessage = "A message is required";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    if (!strlen($message) > 15) {
      $errmessage = "At least 15 letters, numbers, and whitespace required";
    }
  }
  $code = test_input($_POST["code"]);
  if (empty(test_input($_POST["code"]))) {
    $errcode = "Verify that you're human";
  } else {
    $code = test_input($_POST["code"]);
    if (!test_input($_POST['code']) == $string) {
      $errcode = "Match the scrambled code";
    }
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($errfirstname == "" && $errlastname == "" && $errtelephone == "" && $erremail == "" && $errsubject == "" && $errcode == "" && $errmessage == "") {
      $email_from = 'mikethebos@icloud.com';
      $email_body = "Message from: $firstname $lastname\r\nPhone number: $telephone\r\nE-mail address: $email\r\nSubject: $subject\r\nMessage: $message";
      $to = $email_from;
      $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
      mail($to,$subject,$email_body,$headers);
      echo "SENT";
    }
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The Bash Catalog - Contact Us</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label for="firstname">First Name:  </label><input type="text" size="10" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?= isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="John" /><span class="error">  * <?php echo $errfirstname;?></span></p>
    <p><label for="lastname">Last Name:  </label><input type="text" name="lastname" size="15" id="lastname" value="<?= isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="Smith" /><span class="error">  * <?php echo $errlastname;?></span></p>
    <p><label for="telephone">Phone number (+country):  </label><input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?= isset($_POST['telephone']) ? $_POST['telephone'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="+10123456789" minlength="7" maxlength="19" /><span class="error">   <?php echo $errtelephone;?></span></p>
    <p><label for="email">E-mail address:  </label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="25" value="<?= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="JohnSmith@example.com" /><span class="error">  * <?php echo $erremail;?></span></p>
    <p><label for="subject">Subject:  </label><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="23" value="<?= isset($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="New Linux Distrobution" /><span class="error">   <?php echo $errsubject;?></span></p>
    <p class="message"><label class="message" for="message">Message:  </label><textarea name="message" class="message" id="message" cols="60" rows="20" placeholder="Type you message or comments"><?php if(isset($_POST['message'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['message']); }?></textarea><span class="error">  * <?php echo $errmessage;?></span></p>
    <img src="captcha.php"/>
    <p><label for="code">Scrambled code:  </label><input type="text" name="code" id="code" /><span class="error">  * <?php echo $errcode;?></span></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></p>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

captcha.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
//  $lower = chr(rand(97, 122));
//  $upper = chr(rand(65, 90));
//  $rcomb = array($lower, $upper);
//  $srand = array_rand($rcomb, 1);
//  $ssrand = (string)$srand;
//  $string .= $ssrand;
    $int = rand(0,25);
    $a_z = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $rand_letter = $a_z[$int];
    $string .= $rand_letter;
}
$_SESSION["random_code"] = $string;
$dir = 'font/';
$dirFonts = glob($dir . '*.{ttf}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomFont = $dirFonts[array_rand($dirFonts)];
$fontBox = imagettfbbox(70, 0, $randomFont, $_SESSION["random_code"]);
$fontx = $fontBox[2] + 10;
$fonty = $fontBox[3] + 10;
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($fontx + 25, $fonty + 70); // size of image wxh
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 200, 100, 90); // red
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $fontx + 30, $fonty + 70, $white);
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $rr = rand(0, 255);
    $rg = rand(0, 255);
    $rb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rr, $rg, $rb);
    $poly_val = array();
    $randomn = rand(3, 20);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $randomn; $i++){
        $rx = rand(0, $fontx + 30);
        $ry = rand(0, $fonty + 60);
        array_push($poly_val, $rx, $ry);
}
    ImageFilledPolygon($image, $poly_val, $randomn, $colorr);
}
imagettftext($image, 70, 0, 5, $fonty + 65, $black, $randomFont, $_SESSION["random_code"]);
for ($x = 0; $x < 1500; ++$x) {
    $fontty = $fonty / 2;
        $amplitude = rand(0, $fontty + 70);
        $randcoe = rand(0, 180);
        $y = 20 + $amplitude * sin(deg2rad($x-$randcoe));
        $rrr = rand(0, 255);
    $rrg = rand(0, 255);
    $rrb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorrr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rrr, $rrg, $rrb);
        imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, $colorrr);
        $ax = $x;
        imagesetpixel($image, $ax++, $y++, $colorrr);
        $rrr = rand(0, 255);
    $rrg = rand(0, 255);
    $rrb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorrr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rrr, $rrg, $rrb);
    imagesetpixel($image, $ax++, $y++, $colorrr);
    $rrr = rand(0, 255);
    $rrg = rand(0, 255);
    $rrb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorrr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rrr, $rrg, $rrb);
    imagesetpixel($image, $ax++, $y++, $colorrr);
    $rrr = rand(0, 255);
    $rrg = rand(0, 255);
    $rrb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorrr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rrr, $rrg, $rrb);
    imagesetpixel($image, $ax++, $y++, $colorrr);
    $rrr = rand(0, 255);
    $rrg = rand(0, 255);
    $rrb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorrr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rrr, $rrg, $rrb);
    imagesetpixel($image, $ax++, $y++, $colorrr);
    $rrr = rand(0, 255);
    $rrg = rand(0, 255);
    $rrb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorrr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rrr, $rrg, $rrb);
    imagesetpixel($image, $ax++, $y++, $colorrr);
        $rrr = rand(0, 255);
    $rrg = rand(0, 255);
    $rrb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorrr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rrr, $rrg, $rrb);
    imagesetpixel($image, $ax++, $y++, $colorrr);
    $rrr = rand(0, 255);
    $rrg = rand(0, 255);
    $rrb = rand(0, 255);
    $colorrr = imagecolorallocate($image, $rrr, $rrg, $rrb);
}
imageline($image, 0, 0, 420, 120, $black);
imageline($image, 420, 0, 0, 120, $color);
imageline($image, 210, 0, 210, 120, $black);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
?>
```

Comment: Not sure why you just dont use recapcha, but the reason not working is `if (!test_input($_POST['code']) == $string) {` is always false, because of the `!` it should be `if (test_input($_POST['code']) != $string) {`

Comment: I'd say adapt googles recaptcha v2... its VERY simple to implement... and there is even a php library already to use.